# Payment Request is Invalid

Tags: ios, applepay, passkit

So I am just starting with Apple Pay and I set up a Merchant ID and a CSR and I believe I did the setup properly but when prompting the Apple Pay View Controller, my program crashes, saying:

```
2016-09-05 00:29:47.244 MoneySender[876:325291] Payment request is invalid: check your entitlements

2016-09-05 00:29:47.259 MoneySender[876:325264] Connection to remote alert view service failed
```

My Code:

```
 let request = PKPaymentRequest()

    let SupportedPaymentNetworks = [PKPaymentNetworkVisa, PKPaymentNetworkMasterCard, PKPaymentNetworkAmex]
    let ApplePayMerchantID = "myMerchantID"
    request.merchantIdentifier = ApplePayMerchantID
    request.supportedNetworks = SupportedPaymentNetworks
    request.merchantCapabilities = PKMerchantCapability.Capability3DS
    request.countryCode = "US"
    request.currencyCode = "USD"
    let contact = PKContact()
    let nc = NSPersonNameComponents()
    nc.familyName = "myName"
    nc.givenName = "myNamw"
    nc.middleName = "myName"
    var phoneNumber = CNPhoneNumber()
    phoneNumber = CNPhoneNumber(stringValue: "myNumber")
    contact.emailAddress = "myEmail"
    contact.name = nc
    let postalAddress = CNMutablePostalAddress()
    postalAddress.city = "myCity"
    postalAddress.country = "United States of America"
    postalAddress.postalCode = "myPostal"
    postalAddress.state = "myState"
    postalAddress.street = "myAddress"

    contact.postalAddress = postalAddress
    contact.phoneNumber = phoneNumber
    request.billingContact = contact
    request.paymentSummaryItems = [
        PKPaymentSummaryItem(label: item_description, amount: NSDecimalNumber(double: item_price))
    ]

     let applePayController = PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController(paymentRequest: request)


    self.presentViewController(applePayController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    applePayButton.hidden = !PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController.canMakePaymentsUsingNetworks(SupportedPaymentNetworks)
```

Entitlements File:

[image]

Comment: Enable Apple Pay in your project settings, on the **Capabilities** tab

Comment: I did @NazmulHasan

Comment: please refer below link step by step you got your solution : https://www.raywenderlich.com/87300/apple-pay-tutorial

Comment: I did @SandyPatel. That was the tutorial I was following but I am not getting the Apple Pay View Controller to even show up

Comment: @Ryan  request.merchantIdentifier = @"merchant.com.example";

Comment: @Ryan did you get your merchant id  from  Apple? If so ,The issue here. The library you using it wasn't correctly configuring the merchant id

Comment: I did get it from Apple. How should I deal with that? I noticed my Entitlements file is almost empty except for `com.apple.developer.in-app-payments`. @NazmulHasan Could that be the problem?

Comment: @Ryan yes . exactly same taking about my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the entitlements file in its entirety:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.developer.in-app-payments</key>
    <array>
        <string>my-merchant-id</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: This worked. It said those entitlements do not match the one in my provisioning profile. I went back into my Capabilities tab and it said there was an issue but the Fix Issue button was available. After clicking it, everything worked fine! Thanks!